# Is it possible to get parameters from the pull request for Control Options on Azure Devops Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple pipeline on Azure dev ops that has 4 jobs

- Npm i
- Npm run tests
- Npm version Bump
- Npm release

That works. At this moment version bump does only 'patch' every time as a PR is made to the master branch. So it releases only patch versions... I have a custom condition for that:
`contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')`. Well what I want is to add one more condition here that decides to bump version dynamically as patch, major or minor for example... So I was thinking to get that parameter from the pull request title or description sth like that..:

`contains(variables['Build.PR.Title'], 'patch')`
`contains(variables['Build.PR.Title'], 'major')`
`contains(variables['Build.PR.Title'], 'minor')`

That is indeed 3 different jobs that will fire if the pr title has 'patch', 'major' or 'minor'.. Is it possible to do something like that or is there a easier way?:)

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from Shamrai Aleksander`s suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Devops pipeline does not pass the title of prs. You can find here the predefined variables: [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). To get detailed information of active Pull Request you may use Rest Api [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) with `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId`. As example to get the title:

1. Add a custom variable [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) like Custom.PRTitle.
2. Set the access to the PAT in your job. [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)
3. Add first step as script to read and save the title of your pull requests, like with PowerShell:

```
$user = ""
$token = "$(System.AccessToken)"
$teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"
$PRId = "$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
$orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uriGetActivePr = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/pullrequests/$PRId"

$resultPR = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetActivePr -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Custom.PRTitle]"$resultPR.title
```

Then you can use your new variable in your conditions, like:

```
and(contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), contains(variables['Custom.PRTitle'], 'patch'))
```